# trigger event after specific time

Tags: php, mysql

How do you trigger an event or function after a certain time?

For instance, someone ordered something online and it has a payment due date of February 13 7:45AM. When the customer haven't paid anything before this date, his order will be automatically cancelled.

I don't know how to start coding that kind of situation.

Comment: Maybe cron jobs can solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, a cron job would be used to manage tasks like that; though MySQL does have its own [timed event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)

Comment: well i'm using phpmyadmin. i don't know anything about cron so i better start studying. anyway thank you!

Comment: phpmyadmin is simply a front-end tool that lets you send commands to a MySQL database, you can issue CREATE EVENT commands through phpmyadmin, or via a PHP script if you want. The events will execute regardless of how thety are created

Comment: how can i use event scheduler using php script? all i see is commands for phpmyadmin but no codes for creating or altering the event scheduler using php

Comment: phpmyadmin provides a SQL entry form, you use that

Comment: ok. i was planning on creating schedules for reservations. when the user didn't pay after his due date of payment, i want to automatically cancel his reservation. anyway thank you

Comment: Event scheduler page has moved to a [new address](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/event-scheduler.html)

Comment: @Fabian - or an even newer page, given that MySQL 5.6 is rather out of date now