# Is PHP sleep() appropriate for communicating change to REST API after a long wait

Tags: php, twilio-php

I'm looking for a way to limit the duration of a 'room' in Twilio REST API: Rooms. The API provides the function:

```
$room = $client->video->rooms("RMXXX")->update("completed");
```

I want to have a room complete X seconds after its creation. 
My thought was that in the same PHP script where the room is created:

```
$room = $client->video->rooms->create([...my parameters]);
```

I could use `sleep()` for X seconds (eg. 1800 seconds) then call the  `update("completed")` function.

I'm concerned about the impact of this approach on [1] calls to the script from other clients during the 'sleep' period, and [2] server performance in general (I'm using a shared server).

Comment: in short, no. you need a semaphore-like mechanism outside your PHP script,  to manage concurrent call.

Comment: @Daniel J. Anderson - any suggestions? Are you taliking about something like a daemon?

Comment: As already stated, you'll need to have a semaphore-like mechanism to handle this. An ad-hoc solution could be one where you store the room ID as a database entry along with either its creation or expiration date. Then, you could have a CRON process running every so often (e.g. every minute) to find expired rooms and call the delete method on the room ID. Again, this method is ad-hoc and there are likely far better ways to handle this. Consider doing some additional research into this subject.

Comment: Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786884/trigger-event-after-specific-time

Comment: It's a bit late, but there's a caveat to the above: you'll still run into issues with race conditions where it's possible that a request will cause the room to be used just after it's deleted. It's a very low likelihood, but it can still happen. That being said, if the API provides appropriate exceptions or error codes for such a situation, you can catch these and make the client respond appropriately.